# blank substitute inside a substitution changes matched string to empty

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I'm trying following piece of code. Basically this code should not be changing $data as per my understanding. Am I missing somethings? I'm using 5.22.3(strawberry perl).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
my $data = 'we are here';
$data =~ s///g;
print "DATA1: $data\n";
$data =~ s{(we)}{
    my $x1 = $1;
    $x1 =~ s///g;
    print "x1: ^^$x1^^\n";
    "$x1"
}e;
print "DATA2: $data\n";
```

O/P-

```
DATA1: we are here
x1: ^^^^
DATA2:  are here
```

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. The `$x1 =~ s///g;` is deleting everything in `$x1` instead of deleting nothing (as it should).

Comment: same issue with 5.28.2 strawberry perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except when used by `split`, an empty pattern tells the match/substitute operator to use the last pattern to successfully match.

For example,

```
$ perl -e'$_ = "abba"; s//c/g if /a/ || /b/; CORE::say;'
cbbc
```

This means that

```
$x1 =~ s///g;
```

is equivalent to

```
$x1 =~ s/(we)//g;
```

To bypass that exception, you can use

```
$x1 =~ s/(?:)//g;
```

Say your real situation uses

```
$re = ...;
s/$re//g;
```

You could use

```
$re = ...;
s/(?:$re)//g;
```

or

```
$re = ...;
$re = qr/$re/;
s/$re//g;
```

---

Quote [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html),

> **The empty pattern //**
>
> If the *PATTERN* evaluates to the empty string, the last *successfully* matched regular expression is used instead. In this case, only the `g` and `c` flags on the empty pattern are honored; the other flags are taken from the original pattern. If no match has previously succeeded, this will (silently) act instead as a genuine empty pattern (which will always match).

Comment: It could be interesting to know where this feature is useful in practice?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, No idea. Never seen it used. The example I used is easier with this feature than without, but does one ever need to do that? I effectively used it as a backreference that spans /g matches, but backreferences are rarely used in the first place.